# Python function for calculating compound interest percentage

Tags: python, function, math

I'm new to programming, so any experienced programmer will probably be able to answer this question easily.

I am trying to write a Python function which will tell me what percentage compound interest is necessary to end up with a specific sum. For example, if I deposited $100, and after 17 years of compound interest I have $155, the function will tell me what percentage interest was I receiving. I wrote the following function, with 'start' being the original sum deposited, 'finish' the sum I ended up with, and 'years' the number of years it accrued interest. I designed it to give a result in decimal points, for example for 1.5% it will show 0.015.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
def calculate(start, finish, years):
    num = start
    percentage = 0
    while num < finish:
        percentage += 0.000001
        for year in range(years):
            num += num * percentage
    return percentage

print(calculate(12000, 55000, 100))
```

It's giving an output of 0.00017499999999999962 (i.e. 0.017499999999999962%), which is totally wrong.

I can't understand where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reset the `num=start` after every time you guess a percentage.

```py
def calculate(start, finish, years):
    num = start
    percentage = 0
    while num < finish:
        num = start
        percentage += 0.000001
        for year in range(years):
            num += num * percentage
    return percentage
    
print(calculate(12000, 55000, 100))
```

However, you'd probably be better off solving this problem by simply re-arranging the compound interest formula:

```
A=P*(1+r/n)^(nt)
```

(where `A` = Final balance, `P` = Initial balance, `r` = Interest rate, `n` = number of times interest applied per time period, and `t` = number of time periods elapsed.)

The rearrangement gives:

```
r=n((A/P)^(1/nt)-1)
```

and putting this into python gives us:

```py
def calculate(start, finish, years):
    num = ((finish / start)**(1/years))-1
    return num

print(calculate(12000.0, 55000.0, 100.0))
```

which gives the expected results.

Comment: This would be a great answer, except the formula is going to be impossible to understand for someone who doesn't already know it, since there is no explanation of what any of the variables `A`, `P`, `r`, `n`and `t` represent.

Comment: Please note `X^nt` would be understood as `(X^n)t` rather than `X^(nt)` by many people, because exponentiation usually takes precedence over multiplication; that's also how LaTeX would parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a one-liner if you understand how compound interest works

```py
def calculate(start, finish, years):
    return (finish/start)**(1/years) - 1

print(calculate(12000, 55000, 100) * 100, '%')
```